# Can this shipping rule be done without an extension?

Tags: shipping

I am using the community version of Magento.  What I want to do it as follows:

Some products will be assigned free shipping regardless of quantity or whatnot.  Other products will have calculated shipping.  Finally, all shipping will be free once a certain subtotal threshold has been met.  Can I do this without using an extension the way the version of magento I am using now is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

1. Create a new attribute which will indicate if your product is eligible for a free shipping.
2. Create a shopping cart price rule which will have a condition that product is shipped for free if the the attribute you created at step 1 is set to "Yes".
3. Enable generic Magento "Free shipping" shipping method and configure its minimum order amount.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info.  I'll google how to make that attribute.  Thanks again.

Comment: The article may help on first two points http://www.immense.net/magento-free-shipping-certain-products/